# Why pushing a values into my array is beeing skipped?

Tags: javascript, react-native

I am developing a React Native App. In my Code i am fetching data from server. This data is used in my ListView which parameter is dataSource. This code works actually. Now i wanted to fill the array with data, only when the values doesn´t exists yet.

**So: Push Value to Array, if index is bigger than -1:**

```
       if (friendsArray.indexOf(x.id) > -1) {
            friendsArray.push(x);
            self.setState({
                dataSource: self.state.dataSource.cloneWithRows(friendsArray)
            });
        }
```

In my debugger i see that, the Line:

```
       friendsArray.push(x);
```

Will be skipped everytime... Any ideas?

Comment: Could it be because `friendsArray.indexOf(x.id) > -1` is false, just a wild guess here ?

Comment: :) No it´s not. self.setState({... is executed correctly. and when debugging, it jumps into the if statement, but skipping friendsArray.push(x);

Comment: That's not really possible ?

Comment: What do you mean by it gets skipped every time? Does it get executed but the array is empty afterwards?

Comment: If i debug this code, i never get to the line friendsArray.push(x). In my debugger the next step after checking the condition ( if (friendsArray.indexOf(x.id) > -1)) it brings me directly to self.setState({
                dataSource: self.state.dataSource.cloneWithRows(friendsArray)
            }); So this means for me, that friendsArray.push() is beeing skipped or just ignored...

Comment: Chrome debugger has some bugs. Don't worry, the statement is executed. If you want to be sure, insert a `console.log(friendsArray);` after the push.

Comment: Especially when you use pretty-print or sourcemaps

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I believe you have two errors here.

First, if you want to execute the push when an item is not in the array, you'll want to do `friendsArray.indexOf(x.id) == -1`. Checking for `> -1` is checking that the item already exists in the array.

Second, you're checking if `x.id` is in the array, but then pushing `x`. You probably mean to either be checking if `x` is in the array, or pushing `x.id`? If the former (you want to check if `x` is in the array), you'll need a different solution as objects in javascript will always fail an equality comparison. You would instead probably want to do something like check if any of the objects in friendsArray have an id that matches the id of the object you're trying to push. That could be accomplished with something like this:

```
if (friendsArray.filter(function(a) { return a.id == x.id; }).length == 0) {
// friendsArray does not contain an object with that id
}
```